# Energy of a flux tube

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory

I was reading the paper [Topological Quantum Field Theory, Nonlocal Operators, and Gapped Phases of
Gauge Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4793) by Gukov and Kapustin. I don't understand many of the things in there. But, I think the following question can be asked independently. In section II, 3rd paragraph, the authors talk about a flux tube carrying a flux of $2\pi \alpha$. This means that $\oint_C A =2\pi \alpha $ for every closed loop $C$ enclosing the flux tube. Let's put the flux tube along $(0,0,z)$.Then the gauge field $A$ outside the tube should take the form $A=\frac{\alpha}{r} d\theta$, in $(r,\theta,z)$ coordinates. The energy of this gauge field configuration diverges  with respect to the Hamiltonian term $\int |(d\phi-inA \phi)|^2$ unless $\phi$ satisfies
$$
d\phi-inA \phi=0 \tag{1}
$$
for large $r$. Requiring $\phi$ to be single valued, the above equation has a solution if $n\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}$, which the paper quotes. If this condition is not satisfied $|d\phi|^2$ will decay like $1/r^2$. The question is about the divergence in the energy of such a configuration. If we consider the space as a solid cylinder of height $L$ and radius $R$, the energy will be
$$E\sim \int dr (r d\theta) dz \frac{1}{r^2}= 2\pi \log(R/a)L. \tag{2}$$
Please let me know whether I have done something wrong here. Now instead of considering an infinite line, if we consider a closed flux loop of size $L$, I would expect that for large loops, the energy will have the same qualitative behaviour as in Eq. (2), that is it should diverge linearly with the size of the loop $L$ and logarithmically with the distance from the loop. But they claim that the energy diverges like $\log(L)$. If someone can point out what error I have done in my reasoning it will be helpful.

Comment: Flux is $\int F$, not $\int A$

Comment: I meant $\oint_C A=2\pi \alpha$ for every closed loop enclosing the flux tube. I have edited the question.